# Jquery .Scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a function that checks the window height when the user scrolls and 'if' the window height is at a certain level then an action is fired.. but I can't seem to get it to work... The code I have is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).height() < 100) {
        $(".mobnav").slideUp(10);
    }

});
```

Any reason why this shouldn't work? Some help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Is `height` really what you want, or are you looking for the scroll position?

Comment: Condition seems to be the issue `$(window).height() < 100`

Comment: I think hes trying to find scrollTop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the the `scrollTop` method. The `height` method will return the actual window height, that will only change if the window is resized.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/